# 深さ優先探索の行きがけ順のpython3スクリプト

Tags: python

下記のような深さ優先探索の行きがけ順のpython3スクリプトを、Visual Studio 2019(python)で
デバッグ実行してステップインしてみました。

```py
tree = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

def search(pos):
    print(pos, end=' ')
    for i in tree[pos]:
        search(i)
search(0)
```

1,search(0) posが0,iが1。
2,search(1) posが1,iが3。
3,search(3) posが3,iが7。
4,search(7) posが7,iが空リストのためわからない。
5,search(7) posが3,iが7。
6,search(7) posが3,iが8。
以下続く。

上記の4,search(7)の時、iが空リストを指してどこかに行ってしまったようなのですが、
そこで再帰でもしたのでしょうか、
5,search(7) posが3,iが7。になっています。その後も、
6,search(7) posが3,iが8。になっています。

4,search(7)の時の、iが空リストの時のposが3に戻る理由を教えてください。
また、6,search(7) posが3,iが8。になる理由を教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

> 4,search(7)の時の、iが空リストの時のposが3に戻る理由を教えてください。

search(7)はsearch(3)から呼び出されているので、search(7)が終了するとsearch(3)にもどります。

> また、6,search(7) posが3,iが8。になる理由を教えてください。

search(3)がtree[3]である[7,8]の7を処理したあと、8を処理するからです。

調査用のprintを入れた以下のコードを実行すると、

```
tree = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
def search(pos):
    print("START pos = ", end=' ')
    print(pos)
    for i in tree[pos]:
        print("i = ", end=' ')
        print(i)
        search(i)

    print("END  pos = ", end=' ')
    print(pos)
search(0)
```

以下の結果が得られます。※字下げは手で修正しています。

```
START pos =  0
      i =  1
      START pos =  1
            i =  3
            START pos =  3
                  i =  7
                  START pos =  7
                  END   pos =  7
                  i =  8
                  START pos =  8
                  END   pos =  8
            END   pos =  3
            i =  4
            START pos =  4
                  i =  9
                  START pos =  9
                  END   pos =  9
                  i =  10
                 START pos =  10
                 END   pos =  10
            END  pos =  4
      END  pos =  1
      i =  2
      START pos =  2
            i =  5
            START pos =  5
                  i =  11
                  START pos =  11
                  END   pos =  11
                  i =  12
                  START pos =  12
                  END  pos =  12
            END   pos =  5
           i =  6
           START pos =  6
                 i =  13
                 START pos =  13
                 END   pos =  13
                 i =  14
                 START pos =  14
                 END   pos =  14
           END  pos =  6
      END  pos =  2
END   pos =  0
```